# how can i use unnest generate date array to provide end of month index?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

i want to be able to create a fake index for my data so e.g. if i have an  single order i want it repeated for every date in the array created below.

```
select 
  *
 
  from 
  database.data,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
        '2014-01-01',
        (SELECT
          MAX(Order_Date)
        FROM
          database.data), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS month
```

however this creates an index of the 1st of each month, how can i change this so it's the end of every month? e.g. 2014-01-31, and 1 month interval, onwards

Answer (score 1):

You can use date arithmetics:

```
select d.*, date_sub(date_add(dt, 1, interval 1 month), interval 1 day)
from database.data d
cross join unnest(
    generate_date_array('2014-01-01', (select max(order_date) from database.data), interval 1 month)
) as dt
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 10/14/2020, a new function LAST_DAY is released to do this in one stop:

```sql
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE '2008-11-25', MONTH) AS last_day
```